# Python Pandas - Creating a function to replace repetitive DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, group-by

I am new to Python and have managed to build out the following code which is producing the desired results in four separate dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
x2019 = df.Date.between('2015-06-28','2015-07-04') #Transaction Dates we want to analyze
y2019 = df.First_Purchase_Date.between('2014-01-01','2015-07-04') #customer first purchase dates we want to include in the dataset

TABLE_2019_USA_XX = df.loc[x2019 & y2019 & (df['Region'] == 'USA')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
TABLE_2019_USA_XX['TotalCusts'] = TABLE_2019_USA_XX['New Customer'] + TABLE_2019_USA_XX['Existing Customer']

TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX = df.loc[x2019 & y2019 & (df['Region'] == 'Canada')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX['TotalCusts'] = TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX['New Customer'] + TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX['Existing Customer']

x2018 = df.Date.between('2014-07-23','2014-07-28') #Transaction Dates we want to analyze
y2018 = df.First_Purchase_Date.between('2014-01-01','2014-07-30') #customer first purchase dates we want to include in the dataset

TABLE_2018_USA_XX = df.loc[x2018 & y2018 & (df['Region'] == 'USA')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
TABLE_2018_USA_XX['TotalCusts'] = TABLE_2018_USA_XX['New Customer'] + TABLE_2018_USA_XX['Existing Customer']
TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX = df.loc[x2018 & y2018 & (df['Region'] == 'Canada')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX['TotalCusts'] = TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX['New Customer'] + TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX['Existing Customer']

print(TABLE_2018_USA_XX)
print(TABLE_2019_USA_XX)
print(TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX)
print(TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX)
```

Output

```
FPYear  New Customer    Existing Customer   revenue TotalCusts
2014    0                     23              134   23
2015    12                    32              432   44


FPYear  New Customer    Existing Customer   revenue TotalCusts
2014    432                   421            4315    853
2015    3415                  452            2341    3867

FPYear  New Customer    Existing Customer   revenue TotalCusts
2014    22                  432              4312    454
2015    33                  345              3415    378

FPYear  New Customer    Existing Customer   revenue TotalCusts
2014    5                   35               4312    40
2015    432                 32               6131    464
```

Based on what I've read and feedback I got when building this script,  I know I should be able to build out the above using a function but I can't figure out exactly how to do that.  Can someone please provide a suggestion to get me started.  I'm essentially trying to cut down my script and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a function and pass parameters the dates and region you use as filters:

```py
import pandas as pd
def process(df, start_dt, end_dt, purch_start, purch_end, region):
    mask_date = df['Date'].between(start_dt, end_dt)
    mask_purch_date = df['First_Purchase_Date'].between(purch_start, purch_end)
    mask_region = df['Region'] == region

    temp_df = df[mask_date & mask_purch_date & mask_region].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()

    temp_df['TotalCusts'] = temp_df['New Customer'] + temp_df['Existing Customer']

    return temp_df


TABLE_2019_USA_XX = process(df,'2015-06-28','2015-07-04', '2014-01-01','2015-07-04', 'USA')

TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX = process(df,'2015-06-28','2015-07-04', '2014-01-01','2015-07-04', 'Canada')

TABLE_2018_USA_XX = process(df,'2014-07-23','2014-07-28', '2014-01-01','2014-07-30', 'USA')

TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX = process(df,'2014-07-23','2014-07-28','2014-01-01','2014-07-30', 'Canada')
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you have repeating columns in your dataframes and you are doing the same operation over and over?

```
dfs = ['TABLE_2019_CANADA_XX', 'TABLE_2018_CANADA_XX','TABLE_2018_USA_XX', 'TABLE_2019_USA_XX']

df = pd.concat(dfs)

df.groupby(['FPYear','Region'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()
```

Comment: Correct.  The columns in each of the dataframes are the same but the filters are different (ie DF1 Canada, 2018; DF2 USA, 2018; DF3 Canada, 2019; DF4 USA, 2019).

Comment: @wolfblitz grouping by region sorts that problem no?

Comment: hmmm. You mean grouby region in addition to grouping by year which I'm already doing?  I also have two year columns.  The first one is the year of the transaction and the second one is the year the customer first purchased. I'm currently grouping by first purchase year.